# Problems with structuring and retrieving data from Firebase in Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am designing a litte quiz app but I'm having trouble while retrieving the game data.

[image: data structure]

As you can see in the picture I have an JSON object that contains many *single games*. Each single game has a unique id. My first problem is that each of the games can be available in multiple languages. I know that I could download the hole snap and then looping throw each game but that would mean really long loading times while the app is growing.

**In short form:**

I need to retrieve the following data from the JSON above:

- A random game wich is available in a specific language (need to have the key en for example)
- All games that are available in "en" but not yet in "de"

If it is easier to restructure the data in the JSON, please tell me.

Thanks for helping me.

Comment: How are you retrieving those singleGames id's,` for` loop? or are they stored somewhere?

Comment: @Dravidian I just wanted to say that the only way I know is downloading the hole snapshot (all questions) and then looping trough them in the app. That would work but downloading all questions every time you what to play is quite dump I think.

Comment: Yes but all that i am asking that if they are `autoID`'s i think you will have to download your entire snap to navigate through them..

Answer (score 1):

Answer to your first part :-

```
 let enRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("singleGames").child(singleGamesUID).child("en")

  enRef.observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: {(snap) in
  if let enQuizQuestion = snap.value as? [String:AnyObject]{
          //Question exists : Retrieve Data 

      }else{

        //Question in english doesn't exist
    }
})
```

For your second part
Since you are trying to save iteration time might i suggest you also save your `singleGames` id in a separate `languagesBased` nodes, there is a command in firebase that allows you to search for some keyValues in your child node's , but even that i think would be executing a search algorithm which might be a little more time consuming  :--

```
appServerName:{
  singleGames :{
      uid1:{......
            ......
               ...},
      uid2:{......
            ......
               ...},
      uid3:{......
            ......
               ...}
           },
   enQuestions:{
       uid3 : true
          }
   deQuestions:{
       uid1 : true,   
       uid2 : true
         }
     }
```

Now all you gotta do :-

```
let rootRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("deQuestions").observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: {(qSnap) in

    if let qDict = qSnap.value as? [String:AnyObject]{
            for each in qDict as [String:AnyObject]{
              let deUID = each.0
          }
      }else{

      //No question in dutch language
     }
   })
```